# Google Closure bind / resolve issues with the this keyword

Tags: javascript, oop, this, bind, google-closure-library

What is the *Google Closure*'s solution for resolving the issues with the `this` keyword in JavaScript callback functions. It would be so useful in **OO** style programming.

Is there any conventions or style for **OOP** in *Google Closure*???

**update**
How can I access this.darklayer in ViewportSizeMonitor handler???

```
    goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.events');
goog.require('goog.events.EventType');
goog.require('goog.math.Size');
goog.require('goog.style');

goog.require('goog.dom.ViewportSizeMonitor');

goog.provide('ehsun7b.ajax.AjaxBox');

ehsun7b.ajax.AjaxBox = function (url, containerClass) {
  try {
    this.url = url;
    this.containerClass = containerClass;

    var viwportSize = goog.dom.getViewportSize();
    this.darklayer = goog.dom.createDom("div", {
      "style": "width: " + viwportSize.width + "px;" + "height: " + 
      viwportSize.height + "px;" +
      "background-image: url('css/img/50black.png');" +
      "z-index: 1000;" +
      "position: absolute;" +
      "left: 0px; top: 0px;"
    });

    var vsm = new goog.dom.ViewportSizeMonitor();
    goog.events.listen(vsm, goog.events.EventType.RESIZE, function(e) {
      console.log("this: " + this.darklayer);
    });

    this.container = goog.dom.createDom("div", {
      "class": this.containerClass
    });    
    goog.dom.appendChild(this.darklayer, this.container);
    goog.dom.setTextContent(this.container, "hello ajax box");    

    this.show = function() {
      goog.dom.appendChild(document.body, this.darklayer);
    },

    this.hide = function() {    
      goog.dom.removeNode(this.darklayer);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error: " + e);
  }
};
```

**I changed my class according to the Closure's style this way:**

```
goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.events');
goog.require('goog.events.EventType');
goog.require('goog.math.Size');
goog.require('goog.style');

goog.require('goog.dom.ViewportSizeMonitor');

goog.provide('ehsun7b.ajax.AjaxBox');

ehsun7b.ajax.AjaxBox = function (url, containerClass) {
  try {
    this.url = url;
    this.containerClass = containerClass;

    var viwportSize = goog.dom.getViewportSize();
    this.darklayer = goog.dom.createDom("div", {
      "style": "width: " + viwportSize.width + "px;" + "height: " + 
      viwportSize.height + "px;" +
      "background-image: url('css/img/50black.png');" +
      "z-index: 1000;" +
      "position: absolute;" +
      "left: 0px; top: 0px;"
    });

    var vsm = new goog.dom.ViewportSizeMonitor();
    goog.events.listen(vsm, goog.events.EventType.RESIZE, function(e) {
      console.log("this: " + this.darklayer);
    });

    this.container = goog.dom.createDom("div", {
      "class": this.containerClass
    });    
    goog.dom.appendChild(this.darklayer, this.container);
    goog.dom.setTextContent(this.container, "hello ajax box");                   
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error: " + e);
  }
};

ehsun7b.ajax.AjaxBox.prototype.show = function() {
  goog.dom.appendChild(document.body, this.darklayer);
}

ehsun7b.ajax.AjaxBox.prototype.hide = function() {    
  goog.dom.removeNode(this.darklayer);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`goog.bind` is the general purpose solution. For example:

```
goog.bind(this.someFunction, this);
goog.bind(this.someFunction, this, arg1);
goog.bind(this.someFunction, this, arg1, arg2);
```

The framework is generally designed such that this can be avoided, so it's not common to have to explicitly call `goog.bind`.

For example, `goog.events.EventHandler` automatically binds callbacks to the handler you set in its constructor.

```
var handler = new goog.events.EventHandler(this);
handler.listen(something, 'something', this.someFunction); // no need to bind
```

The array functions also support a handler argument.

```
goog.array.forEach(elements, this.someFunction, this);
var items = goog.array.map(elements, this.someFunction, this);
```

And so on. Most parts of the framework make it pretty easy to do this, it's very well designed for "pseudo-classic" inheritance.

For more details, see http://www.bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php

Comment: Very nice, I'm not so familiar with the styles and convention of `Google Closure`, May I ask you see my class `AjaxBox` in my question update and tell me how can I access `this.darklayer` in ViewportSizeMonitor `handler`???

Comment: Also, do not put your goog.require() statements in the same script tag as the entry point to code that uses the goog.required functions or classes. A goog.require() call adds code to the document after the script tag containing the call. More: https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted