# Object Oriented Javascript and Multiple DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I have a conceptual question about how one would approach a particular problem from an object oriented perspective (note: for those interested in the namespacing here, I am using Google Closure). I am fairly new to the OOP JS game so any and all insight is helpful!

Imagine you want to create an object that initiates a carousel for each DOM element on the page that matches a classname `.carouselClassName`.

Something like this

```
/*
 * Carousel constructor
 * 
 * @param {className}: Class name to match DOM elements against to
 * attach event listeners and CSS animations for the carousel.
 */
var carousel = function(className) {
  this.className = className;

  //get all DOM elements matching className
  this.carouselElements = goog.dom.getElementsByClass(this.className);
}

carousel.prototype.animate = function() {
  //animation methods here
}

carousel.prototype.startCarousel = function(val, index, array) {
  //attach event listeners and delegate to other methods 
  //note, this doesn't work because this.animate is undefined (why?)
  goog.events.listen(val, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, this.animate);
}

//initalize the carousel for each
carousel.prototype.init = function() {
  //foreach carousel element found on the page, run startCarousel
  //note: this works fine, even calling this.startCarousel which is a method. Why?
  goog.dom.array.foreach(this.className, this.startCarousel, carousel);
}

//create a new instance and initialize
var newCarousel = new carousel('carouselClassName');
newCarousel.init();
```

Just playing around with OOP in JS for the first time, I've made a few observations:

1. A property defined in my constructor object (`this.classname`) is available by the `this` operation in other prototype objects.
2. A method defined in my constructor object or in the prototype is not available using this.methodName (see comments above).

Any additional comments on my approach to this are definitely welcome :)

Comment: Constructors should be named uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you do not have your `Carousel` object represent all the carousels on the page. Each one should be a new instance of `Carousel`.

The problem that you are running into with `this` not being assigned properly can be fixed by "binding" those methods to `this` in your constructor.

E.g.

```
function Carousel(node) {
    this.node = node;

    // "bind" each method that will act as a callback or event handler
    this.bind('animate');

    this.init();
}
Carousel.prototype = {
    // an example of a "bind" function...
    bind: function(method) {
        var fn = this[method],
            self = this;
        this[method] = function() {
            return fn.apply(self, arguments);
        };
        return this;
    },

    init: function() {},

    animate: function() {}
};

var nodes = goog.dom.getElementsByClass(this.className),
    carousels = [];

// Instantiate each carousel individually
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) carousels.push(new Carousel(nodes[i]));
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the next question I was going to ask actually - and I agree it seems more appropriate to instantiate each carousel individually. Thanks for demonstrating! One follow-up question re: binding these methods to 'this'. I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527192/google-closure-bind-resolve-issues-with-the-this-keyword). The answer states that you should normally be able to bypass using goog.bind (Closure handles it for you). So, how might I structure this differently to avoid binding events?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [reference for the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). If you call one of the methods from your `newCarousel` object (for example: `newCarousel.init();`), `this` in the init method will point to the object. If you'd call a method on that, it's the same.

You always can retrieve properties from a object reference. If these properties are functions, and won't get executed in the right context (e.g. from an event handler), their `this` won't point to the `newCarousel` any more. Use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to get around that (`forEach` seems to take your third parameter as the context of each call).

Comment: I think that third argument to the forEach might take care of that... I don't use Closure though, so I'm not certain...

Comment: Ah, surely. OP said it works - although I don't understand why because I don't know the lib. Updated answer.